# Laravel: Not getting required data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I am a Laravel newbie so I don't understand why this query is giving me only one user result instead of all entries containing `posts.title` or `posts.description`. This should be a search expression (`%for%`) and use the specific category (`get`).

```
DB::table('posts')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
->join('locations', 'users.id', '=', 'locations.id')
->join('main_categories', 'main_categories.id', '=', 'posts.main_category_id')
->select('posts.*', 'users.*', 'locations.address', 'main_categories.name as cat', DB::raw('ROUND((6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(31.430443800000003)) * COS(RADIANS(locations.lattitude)) * COS(RADIANS(locations.longitude) - RADIANS(74.280726)) + SIN(RADIANS(31.430443800000003)) * SIN(RADIANS(locations.lattitude)))),2) AS DISTANCE'))
->where([['posts.title','like','%for%'],['main_categories.name', '=', 'get']])
->orwhere([['posts.description','like','%for%'],['main_categories.name', '=', 'get']])
->get();
```

I am trying to convert this MySQL query into Laravel format. This MySQL query gives me 3 rows, 2 of one user and 1 row of another user. But in Laravel I only get one user row.

```
SELECT
  posts.title,
  posts.description,
  posts.sub_category_id,
  posts.image,
  posts.created_at,
  posts.main_category_id,
  posts.user_id,
  locations.address,
  ROUND(
    (
      6371 * ACOS(
        COS(RADIANS(31.430443800000003)) * COS(RADIANS(locations.lattitude)) * COS(
          RADIANS(locations.longitude) - RADIANS(74.280726)
        ) + SIN(RADIANS(31.430443800000003)) * SIN(RADIANS(locations.lattitude))
      )
    ),
    2
  ) AS DISTANCE
FROM
  posts
INNER JOIN
  users ON posts.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN
  locations ON users.location_id = locations.id
INNER JOIN
  main_categories ON main_categories.id = posts.main_category_id
WHERE
  (
    (
      posts.title LIKE '%for%' OR posts.description LIKE '%for%'
    ) AND(main_categories.name = 'Get')
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use invalid join in your Laravel query. Instead of

```
->join('locations', 'users.id', '=', 'locations.id')
```

it should be

```
 ->join('locations', 'users.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
```

because in your raw query you use:

```
INNER JOIN
  locations ON users.location_id = locations.id
```